Pine Script - Dynamic Opening Range
Good Morning,
I’m new to Pine Script and I need yoir help.
I'm trying to create a script that create a box from last day 4:14 PM (New York Time) closing price to today, actual price.
The box should be red if actual price is higher and green if lower.
The box should delete at 9:30 AM today.
Could anybody help me to solve this ?
Here is the code :
//@version=5
indicator("Dynamic Opening Range", overlay=true)


// Function to determine if the current time is after 4:14 PM of the last opening day
getLastClosingDayTime() =>
    var int lastCloseTime = na
    if (dayofweek != dayofweek[1])  // New day detected
        if (hour(time, "America/New_York") == 16 and minute(time, "America/New_York") == 14)  // Check if it's 4:14 PM
            lastCloseTime := time, "America/New_York"
    lastCloseTime

// Get the time of the last opening day at 4:14 PM
lastCloseTime = getLastClosingDayTime()

// Get the current time for comparison
currentTime = time

// Define the condition to end the rectangle at 9:30 AM
endRectangleTime = timestamp("America/New_York", year(currentTime), month(currentTime), dayofmonth(currentTime), 9, 30)

// Draw the rectangle if the last closing time is valid and the current time is before 09:30 AM of the current day
var box myBox = na
if (not na(lastCloseTime) and currentTime < endRectangleTime)
    if (na(myBox))
        myBox := box.new(left=lastCloseTime, top=high, right=bar_index, bottom=low, border_color=color.green, border_width=2, bgcolor=color.new(color.green, 90))
    else
        box.set_left(myBox, lastCloseTime)
        box.set_right(myBox, bar_index)
        box.set_top(myBox, high)
        box.set_bottom(myBox, low)

// If it's 09:30 AM or later, delete the rectangle
if (currentTime >= endRectangleTime and not na(myBox))
    box.delete(myBox)
    myBox := na

Thanks and best regards,
Max

Hi, Anybody to help me an that ? Thanks. Max.
